# Drop down/Sub-menus in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I'm currently in the process of developing a website. As part of the requirements, I need to include dropdown menu/sub menu from some of the main menu items. I'm able to create main menu items with KeystoneJS but I can't seem to find a tutorial on how to implement sub-menu items. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm assuming you're talking about updating the navigation bar that you get given after running the generator, and not about the admin UI itself?

If so, it will depend on what templating engine you use. I've done this myself with the handlebars template engine. I just added a `locals.subsection`, similar to `locals.section`.

I then updated `routes/middleware` to look like this:

```
locals.navLinks = [
    { label: 'Home',        key: 'home',        href: '/' },
    { label: 'About Us',        key: 'about',       pages: [
        { label: 'What We Do',      subkey: 'whatwedo', href: "/whatwedo" },
        { label: 'Our Journey',     subkey: 'journey',      href: "/journey"    }
        ] },
    { label: 'Blog',        key: 'blog',        href: '/blog' }
];
```

where in the above example, the "About Us" menu item will be a drop down, and the other two will not be. Then on the routes for your individual pages, you'll need to specify the `section`, and also the `subsection` if you want it to be a dropdown. In the above example, the `whatwedo` route has `locals.section: about` and `locals.subsection: whatwedo`.

You'll then need to update your default layout. For me, it's written in handlebars, and so looked like this:

```
{{# each navLinks}}
    {{#if href}}    
        <li {{#ifeq ../../section key}}class="active"{{/ifeq}}>
            <a href="{{ href }}">{{ label }}</a>
        </li>
    {{else}}
        <li class="dropdown{{#ifeq ../../section key}} active{{/ifeq}}">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ label }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {{#each pages}}
                    <li {{#ifeq ../../../subsection subkey}}class="active"{{/ifeq}}>
                        <a href="{{ href }}">{{ label }}</a>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I realise you are probably using jade rather than handlebars, but hopefully you'll be able to 'translate' this code.

Apologies if I've misinterpreted your question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Right on, thanks. That's what I was looking for. I also came across [keystone-menus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-menus). Although I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I'd also not come across that before. Looks like that is relating to the adminUI menus, rather than your public facing webpage though?

Comment: It should work on the frontend. I just can't get it to display.